# babel + textcomp + redefining \LaTeX

Tags: babel, incompatibility, textcomp

I see this with TeXLive 2018, which includes version 3.26 of `babel.sty` (2018/10/16 3.26"). I think this works with some earlier versions of `babel.sty`, but I'm not sure where the cutoff is.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand*{\LaTeX}{hello}
\begin{document}

Testing: \LaTeX

\end{document}
```

When I run PDFLaTeX on this, I do *not* see "Testing: hello" but instead see "Testing: LaTeX". Why can't I redefine the macro `\LaTeX`?

Note that I only see the problem if I use both packages `babel` and `textcomp`; omit either and things work as they should.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because `textcomp` loads a non-ASCII encoding (`ts1enc.def`), and `babel` explicitly checks for that and, if that's the case, it changes the definition of the `\LaTeX` macro. The relevant part of the file:

When `babel` is being loaded it defines the list of non-ASCII encodings:

```
\newcommand\BabelNonASCII %                   vvv Here's the one loaded by textcomp
  {LGR,X2,OT2,OT3,OT6,LHE,LWN,LMA,LMC,LMS,LMU,TS1,T3,TS3}
```

then it saves the original definitions of `\TeX` and `\LaTeX`:

```
\let\org@TeX\TeX
\let\org@LaTeX\LaTeX
\let\ensureascii\@firstofone
```

Now, when the `\begin{document}` is executed, `babel` checks if any of the encodings defined above were loaded:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \in@false
  \bbl@foreach\BabelNonASCII{% is there a non-ascii enc?
    \ifin@\else
      \lowercase{\bbl@xin@{,#1enc.def,}{,\@filelist,}}%
    \fi}%
```

if any, then it redefines `\LaTeX` to be `\ensureascii{\org@LaTeX}` (and a couple more things):

```
  \ifin@ % if a non-ascii has been loaded
    \def\ensureascii#1{{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont#1}}%
    \DeclareTextCommandDefault{\TeX}{\org@TeX}%
    \DeclareTextCommandDefault{\LaTeX}{\org@LaTeX}%
    \def\bbl@tempb#1\@@{\uppercase{\bbl@tempc#1}ENC.DEF\@empty\@@}%
    \def\bbl@tempc#1ENC.DEF#2\@@{%
      \ifx\@empty#2\else
        \bbl@ifunset{T@#1}%
          {}%
          {\bbl@xin@{,#1,}{,\BabelNonASCII,}%
           \ifin@
             \DeclareTextCommand{\TeX}{#1}{\ensureascii{\org@TeX}}%
             \DeclareTextCommand{\LaTeX}{#1}{\ensureascii{\org@LaTeX}}%
           \else
             \def\ensureascii##1{{\fontencoding{#1}\selectfont##1}}%
           \fi}%
      \fi}%
    \bbl@foreach\@filelist{\bbl@tempb#1\@@}%  TODO - \@@ de mas??
    \bbl@xin@{,\cf@encoding,}{,\BabelNonASCII,}%
    \ifin@\else
      \edef\ensureascii#1{{%
        \noexpand\fontencoding{\cf@encoding}\noexpand\selectfont#1}}%
    \fi
  \fi}
```

The problem is that `\org@LaTeX` is defined when `babel` is loaded, and `\LaTeX` is _re_defined `\AtBeginDocument`, so your `\renewcommand` is overwritten.

To overcome this you'll need to redefine `\LaTeX` either before `babel` is loaded, after the `\begin{document}`, or `\AtBeginDocument` after `babel` is loaded:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \renewcommand*{\LaTeX}{hello} % Option 1
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
% \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\LaTeX}{hello}} % Option 2
\begin{document}
% \renewcommand*{\LaTeX}{hello} % Option 3

Testing: \LaTeX

\end{document}
```

1. Option 1 works because when `babel` is loaded, `\LaTeX` is `hello`, so `\org@LaTeX` becomes `hello` and your definition is used.
2. Option 2 works because the `\AtBeginDocument` command adds the argument to the end of the token list, so your redefinition is executed after `babel`'s. It is essentially the same as doing it after the `\BeginDocument`.
3. Option 3 trivially works because nothing happens between your redefinition and the usage of the command.

This change happened in `babel` version `3.23`, when the encodings `TS1, T3, TS3` were added to the non-ASCII list:

```
% Line 8996 of an up-to-date (26-10-2018) `babel.dtx`:
% \changes{babel~3.23}{2018/08/28}{Added TS1, T3, TS3}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. This is presumably not a bug (right?), but as you point out,  it is new behavior. In my case, I am dealing with a partially autogenerated LaTeX file, via Sphinx, and I think option 2 will work.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri It's documented so it's certainly not a bug. According to the documentation it's introduced to fix a bug when using other scripts (section **1.20 Selecting scripts**). I couldn't yet manage to reproduce the bug with an older version of `babel`...

Comment: There was a bug, indeed, but the fix is not correct either. I'll fix it.